# Alteryx workflow schedule is stuck at queue

Tags: mysql, alteryx

I have a scheduled workflow that supposed to run on my computer. Though the job is stuck in the queue. The actions stated in this [link](https://help.alteryx.com/2019.2/ScheduleNewJob.htm?tocpath=Workflows%7C_____7) that I followed are as the following:

```
1. With the saved workflow open, click and click My Computer.  OK
2. In the Schedule Workflow window, select a run option: Run the workflow from its original location on disk: Saves the workflow and schedules it to your computer. You can edit the workflow without needing to update the schedule, but removing, moving, or renaming the workflow will cause the schedule to fail. OK
3.Select schedule frequency. OK
4. Complete the scheduled date and time details. Scheduled workflows and timezones OK Scheduled workflows run at the scheduled time in the time zones in which the server is located. Workflows scheduled to run at 1:30 am or 2:30 am may run multiple times and at a time later than you selected due to daylight savings time. OK
5. Click OK. OK
```

The workflow runs just fine when I manually run it, but gets stuck in the schedule which can be seen in the image.
[image]

Comment: did you chekc the erroro log of mysql and the slow query log. check also the event viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging, the I resolved the issue with below steps:

```
 1. "Options" 
 2. "Advanced options"
 3. "System settings"  
   -> Click "Next" 
   -> Select "Designer and Scheduler Only"  
   -> Click "Next" (6 times)  
   -> Click "Run as a different user"  
   -> Enter your "Domain", "Username", "Password"  
   -> Click "Next" until the end and Click "Finish" 
 4. Click "Options"
 5. Click "Schedule Workflow" 
 6. Select "My Computer"  
  -> Select the time and interval options
```

You should be good to go!